# Cant you just see the NFT that would be minted next?

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721

All images and the metadata to each NFT is uploaded somewhere beforehand right? And the Links include the tokenId of the NFT right?

Then anyone can just look at the current tokenId in the Smart Contract and go the link of the next tokenId to see which traits it has or how it looks. So you could just wait for the right moment to do your mint to get the most "interesting" one.

Is that correct or am I missing something? Of course this is just theoretical. In practice it is probably impossible to time the correct mint as many transactions happen at the same time. But still you would see what your next mint would bring.

Answer (score 1):

It mainly depends on how the URI is stored within the contract.

One option is to have only one link to a folder and token is equal to the metadata names. If this option is used, you could potentially see the upcoming NFT metadata, but usually, it is set moments before the launch, so you really have no time to sniff the good ones, unless the collection doesn't get sold out in which case do you even want the NFTs?

The second option is to send the URI to the contract upon mint, so every NFT has its own URI and it is sent by the owner upon mint.

To solve this problem most projects simply use the temporary "pre-reveal" images, which are all the same and once all the NFTs get minted the actual NFTs get revealed.

There's also other methods to prevent sniffing the metadata, but there were cases when your theory was used in practise as well.